# Select Minus with fixed column in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to do a MINUS operation between two tables like these:

**table1:**

```
employee_id |   job  | sector
----------- | ------ | ------
10          | a      | 1
10          | a      | 2
10          | b      | 4
```

**table2:**

```
job  | sector
---- | ------
a    | 1
a    | 2
a    | 3
b    | 1
b    | 4
c    | 1
c    | 2
```

and as result I want, for every employee_id, the {job,sector} not connected in table1.

**RESULT:**

```
employee_id | job | sector
----------- | --- | ------
10          | a   | 3
10          | b   | 1
10          | c   | 1
10          | c   | 2
```

Is it possible?

I hope I have written in a clear way! Thanks!

Comment: How do you get `employee_id` if the tables are not linked?

Comment: Employee_id is a FK to another table called Employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select the complete data set, i.e. employee_id X job/sector. From these remove the existing table1 entries to get the lacking ones. (I've renamed your table `table2` to `job_sector` for readability. I also suppose you have an `employee` table.)

```
select e.employee_id, js.job, js.sector
from employee e
cross join job_sector js
minus
select employee_id, job, sector
from table1;
```

Comment: PS: You suppose well, I have the 'employee' table!

Answer (score 0):

Left join, where t2 is null

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
let join table2 t2
  on t1.job = t2.job
  and t1.sector = t2.sector
where t2.job is null
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like just a `left join` (or `not in` or `not exists`):

```
select 10 as employee_id, t2.*
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.job = t1.job and t2.sector = t1.sector
where t1.job is null;
```

I am a bit confused on how you get the employee id *if the tables are not linked*.

If you have multiple employees in `t1`, then you can do:

```
select e.employee_id, t2.*
from (select distinct employee_id from t1) e cross join
     table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.job = t1.job and t2.sector = t1.sector and
        e.employee_id = t1.employee_id
where t1.job is null;
```

Comment: Well done! I have multiple employee_id in t1 and your second solution work fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it by doing a **left join**. You query will look something like this:

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM TABLE2 T2 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE1 T1
     ON T2.JOB = T1.JOB AND T2.SECTOR = T2.SECTOR
WHERE T1.JOB IS NULL;
```

Though table must be linked in order to get the employee id.